# Newbie: access attributes of model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two model classes: **Cars** and **Customers**,

Model **Cars**:

```
class car < ActiveRecord::Base

  #car has attribute :town_code

  has_many :customers

end
```

Model **Customers**:

```
class customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # customer has attribute :first_name, :last_name

  belongs_to :car
end
```

In my **controller**, I have the following code:

```
my_customer = Customer.find_all_by_first_name('John')
p my_customer.last_name
p my_customer.car_id
```

But I got `no attribute 'car_id'` **error**, I also got `no attribute 'last_name'` **error**.

**---Question 1:---**

I checked my database, I do have **'car_id'** and **'last_name'** columns on my **customer** table. Why I can not access them in the way how my controller code does?

**---Question 2:---**

but the code : `my_customer.map(&:car_id)` is working for accessing car_id, however, I do not quite understand the code `.map(&:car_id)`, what does it do? Can anyone explains to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you aren't able to do `my_customer.last_name` is that `my_customer` is not a Customer here but an array of Customers, since you did `find_all`.  That's also why `my_customer.map(&:car_id)` works.  What that bit of code means is: For each object in the array my_customer, call the method `car_id` and insert the results into a new array -- and return that new array.

If customer belongs to car, you need a car_id in the customer table (which corresponds to an id column in the car table).  Also, you shouldn't have last_name in the car table, but rather in the customer table.

It sounds like you may need to step back and gain a better understanding of [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).  It's not clear to me why a customer would belong_to a car, anyway.

Comment: Hi, that is my typo when I said I have car_id and last_name in 'car' table, actually they are in 'customer' table. It is just my typo. I am mostly concern about the code ".map(&:car_id)", what does it do?

Comment: what does '&' means in .map(&:car_id) ? Only mean to call the method?

Comment: `map` takes a block, which gets run for each item in the collection, so you'd often do something like `my_array.map{|item|item.car_id}`.  The `&` turns a method into a block; essentially you're now passing in a block that consists of "call the method".  It's basically a shortcut.